# Stubbing out parameters with pre-existing values in FakeItEasy

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

This is a bit of an odd one. I'm trying to stub a method which has out parameters, I don't care about what the parameters are so I'm ignoring the arguments. It looks like this:

```
List<Foo> ignored;
A.CallTo(() => fake.Method(out ignored))
  .Returns(something);
```

This works without any problems when the stubbed method is called like so:

```
List<Foo> target;
var result = service.Method(out target);
```

However, it doesn't work when the `target` is pre-initialised. For example:

```
List<Foo> target = new List<Foo>();
var result = service.Method(out target);
```

When I inspect the `Tag` on the fake, I can see that the out parameters are being recorded as `<NULL>` so I suspect they're not matching when the out target is already set to something. I've tried setting the `ignored` in my test to `new List<Foo>()` and also tried `A<List<Foo>>.Ignored` but neither has any effect on the result.

So my question is, does anyone know how to stub a method with out parameters if the out parameter target already has a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: since [FakeItEasy 1.23.0](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/releases/tag/1.23.0) the initial value of `out` parameters is ignored when matching, so no need for `WithAnyArguments`**

, Five minutes later and I've found an acceptable solution (in this scenario). As I'm not interested in what arguments are passed to this method, so if I use the `WithAnyArguments()` method then it seems to work; this must shortcut the argument checking all together, I guess.

The final code is:

```
List<Foo> ignored;
A.CallTo(() => fake.Method(out ignored))
  .WithAnyArguments()
  .Returns(something);
```

This obviously doesn't solve the problem if I *don't* want to ignore all the arguments. I'll only accept this answer if nobody has a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Nope, this is the solution. I have been thinking about a nice syntax for this for years but never came up with anything that was "quite there", if you have any ideas please let me know.